# CSS attribute selectors: how to escape newlines within attribute value?

Tags: css, escaping, css-selectors

I have a link with an `href` attribute that has carriage returns in its value (HTML cannot change):

```
<a href="
    http://google.com
">Testing</a>
```

I originally thought a backslash can be used to escape a carriage return character (U+000D) when used inside of a string, but then read this in the CSS spec:

> Any character (**except a hexadecimal digit, linefeed, carriage return, or form feed**) can be escaped with a backslash to remove its special meaning. For example, "\"" is a string consisting of one double quote.

Is this possible? I've tried using `\a` and `\n` as well without any luck.

http://jsfiddle.net/AHuvh/1/

Comment: I believe the correct format is `\n` rather than just "\" followed by a new line... It could also be `\a`

Comment: @DrydenLong: I've tried both, no luck :(

Comment: Yeah, I just tested on the fiddle you provided, but couldn't get it to work either. I found this link though, that may help you out: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes

Comment: You may have to try targeting the elements using Javascript and applying your styles that way. I'm not 100% but I imagine JS is better suited to handle the carriage returns...

Comment: Note that `\a` is a line feed; a carriage return would be represented by the Unicode escape `\d` instead. That is not relevant in CSS though; all newlines are normalized to line feeds only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason why the selector that you have doesn't work:

```
a[href="\
    http://google.com\
"]
```

Is because:

> **First, inside a string, a backslash followed by a newline is ignored (i.e., the string is deemed not to contain either the backslash or the newline).** Outside a string, a backslash followed by a newline stands for itself (i.e., a DELIM followed by a newline).

This is mentioned in the paragraph above the one you quote from [section 4.1.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters), and why it says that newlines are one of the characters that cannot be escaped with a backslash.

This makes it equivalent to the following selector:

```
a[href="    http://google.com"]
```

Which would only match your element if its attribute value did not contain any newlines.

That said, it *is* in fact possible to match an element by an attribute value containing newlines. However, CSS makes this a little complicated:

1. To represent a newline in a CSS string, you need to use the `\a` escape sequence (case insensitive, up to 6 hex digits). This is stated in [section 4.3.7](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#strings), on strings (which are treated the same whether in a property value or an attribute selector):

   > A string cannot directly contain a newline. To include a newline in a string, use an escape representing the line feed character in ISO-10646 (U+000A), such as "\A" or "\00000a". This character represents the generic notion of "newline" in CSS.

   `\n` has no special meaning in CSS; in fact, it's the same as `n`.
2. If a space directly follows an escape sequence such as `\a`, that space must be doubled so that the space character directly following the escape sequence can be consumed. Refer to section 4.1.3 again, which states:

   > Only one white space character is ignored after a hexadecimal escape. Note that this means that a "real" space after the escape sequence must be doubled.

   This may be why you couldn't get it to work even with `\a`. Understandably, it's an incredibly obscure rule, especially when working with whitespace characters.

This results in the following selector, [with the styles applying correctly](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/AHuvh/6):

```
a[href="\a     http://google.com\a"]
```

Notice that there are *five* space characters between the first `\a` and the URL, whereas in comparison there are only four spaces following the newline in your HTML.

Comment: In JS, you can use [`CSS.escape("\n    http://google.com\n")`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape) to get the correct value. The full selector can be obtained by using `\`a[href=${CSS.escape("\n    http://google.com\n")}]\``.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `~` (`[attr~=value]`):

> Represents an element with an attribute name of `attr` whose value is a whitespace-separated list of words, one of which is exactly "value".

```
a[href~="http://google.com"] {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/AHuvh/2/)

Comment: sorry, dummy edit so I could change my downvote into an upvote

Comment: @user3019334 Alright - let's see if any other answers come in. But, *"Any character (except a hexadecimal digit, linefeed, **carriage return**,"* sounds like it's not possible. I would definitely be surprised if someone came up with a CSS solution :)

Comment: Nice one @BoltClock'saUnicorn I had a feeling you would stop by as this was tagged as `css-selectors`. I learn something new every time you answer :)